# Integral of impulse-train

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, definite-integrals, fourier-series

Can someone check if I have this right please? (Or point out where I'm wrong!)

I have a (real) impulse-train with maximum amplitude $1$ and period $R+1$, given by

$$s(x)=\frac {1}{R+1}+\sum_{k=1}^R\frac {\cos \bigl(\frac {2k\pi x}{R+1}\bigr)}{R+1}$$

The indefinite integral is (I think)

$$\int s(x) dx=\frac {x}{R+1}+\sum_{k=1}^R\frac {\sin \bigl(\frac {2k\pi x}{R+1}\bigr)}{2k\pi}+C$$

I am looking for the definite integral over the range $0$ to $R+1$, given by

$$\int_0^{R+1} s(x) dx=\int s(R+1) dx-\int s(0) dx$$

$$=\frac {R+1}{R+1}+\sum_{k=1}^R\frac {\sin \bigl(\frac {2k\pi (R+1)}{R+1}\bigr)}{2k\pi}-\frac {0}{R+1}-\sum_{k=1}^R\frac {\sin \bigl(\frac {0}{R+1}\bigr)}{2k\pi}$$

$$=1+\sum_{k=1}^R\frac {\sin 2k\pi}{2k\pi}$$

$$=1+\sum_{k=1}^R\operatorname{sinc}2k\pi$$

$$=1$$

(Because $\operatorname{sinc}2k\pi=0$ for all integer values of $k$.)

Could someone please confirm if I have this right, or point out where the error is?

Comment: You need braces `{}` instead of brackets `[]` for grouping.

Comment: Changed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all looks good to me. With a bit less calculation, you could have also just said that the cosines all have periods that divide $R+1$ so their integral over an interval of length $R+1$ is $0$, so what you have is just $\frac1{R+1}$ integrated over an interval of length $R+1$ (which is $1$).

Comment: I guess I took the scenic route! Question answered.